# Find $\inf\{\operatorname{Frac}(\sqrt{5}n) : n\in\Bbb N_+\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find $\inf \{\operatorname{Frac}(\sqrt{5}n) \colon n \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$

Just for some information that $\operatorname{Frac}(x) \in [0,1)$ s.t $x - \operatorname{Frac}(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$

It looks to me that the $\inf$ is 0. I am not so sure how to prove it.

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent, you use $\operatorname{frac}$ and $\operatorname{Frac}$. Are they the same? Is it that $\operatorname{frac}(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: They are the same

Comment: $$\text{Frac}(\sqrt{5} F_{2k+1}) = \frac{2}{\phi^{2k+1}} \to 0\quad\text{ as }\;\;k \to \infty$$ where $F_k $ is the $k^{th}$ Fibonacci number and $\phi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is the golden mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Theorem by Dirichlet which says that the fract part of $n\alpha$ is dense in $[0,1)$ if $\alpha$ is irrational.

Anyhow, this can be proven by the Pigeonhole Principle, and the following basic idea is enough for what you want:

Divide $[0,1)$ in $m$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{m}$. Look at the fractional part of 
$\sqrt{5}, 2 \sqrt{5},.., (m+1) \sqrt{5}$. Two of them must be in the same mini interval, and then the fractional part of the difference must be in $(0, \frac{1}{m})$.

Done.

Comment: what is pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @josh If you divide some objects into groups, and you have more objects that groups, then there is a group which contains more than one object...It is called the Pigeonhole, because sometimes is stated as "if some pigeons go into some pigeonholes, and if there are more pigeons than pigeonholes, then there is a hole which contains at least two pigeons".

Comment: thanks, what does dense in [0,1) mean?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: why do we have to take the difference of the fractional part in the same interval?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $a_n$ be the fractional part of $\sqrt{5}n$, and let $N$ be a large positive integer. Consider $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_{N+1}$. Then by the pigeonhole principle there are $i$ and $j$, with $1\le i\lt j \le N+1$, such that $|a_j-a_i|\lt \dfrac{1}{N}$.

This will not quite do it. But something fairly close will.

Comment: why do we have to take the difference of the fractional part in the same interval?

Comment: We want the fractional parts of $\sqrt{5}i$ and $\sqrt{5}j$ to be close to **each other** to make the fractional part of $\sqrt{5}(j-i)$ small. But it doesn't quite work, hence my "this will not quite do it" since the fractional part of $\sqrt{5}j$ could be smaller than the fractional part of $\sqrt{5}i$, putting the difference close to $1$, not $0$.

Comment: I still cant figure out what would the "something fairly close will" be, any more hints, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line $L$ given by $y=mx$ on the two-dimensional real torus $T=([0,1]\times[0,1])/\sim$.  If $m$ is irrational, it is known that $L$ is dense in $T$.  In particular, $L$ intersects to a dense subset in $(\{0\}\times[0,1])\subset T$, which represents the points $mn$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.